# Vaadin everything shifts after changing view

Tags: java, layout, vaadin

If I change the view from my main menu to another page and then return to my main menu somehow everything on my main menu page shifts to the top left by a about one centimeter. I dont know if I'm missing something? 
This is the constructor for my main menu:

```
public MainMenuView() {
    lHeader.setWidth(null);

    addButton.setWidth("100px");
    addButton.setHeight("100px");
    searchButton.setWidth("100px");
    searchButton.setHeight("100px");
    editButton.setWidth("100px");
    editButton.setHeight("100px");


    vLayout.addComponent(buttons);
    this.setCompositionRoot(vLayout);
    buttons.setComponentAlignment(lHeader, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);


    addMerchant.setStyleName("mystyle");
    showMerchants.setStyleName("mystyle");
    merchantSearch.setStyleName("mystyle");
    lHeader.addStyleName("mylabelstyle");
    addButton.setStyleName("addButtonStyle");
    searchButton.addStyleName("searchButtonStyle");
    editButton.addStyleName("editButtonStyle");
    addLabel.addStyleName("add");
    searchLabel.addStyleName("search");
    editLabel.addStyleName("edit");


    addButton.addClickListener(e -> addMerchant());
    editButton.addClickListener(e -> showMerchants());
    searchButton.addClickListener(e -> merchantSearch());

}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example, that shows the error.  Also what Vaadin version is this (7,8,10+)?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is occurred when some styles are duplicated in your first and second pages. 
   /you need to check them./
2. You need to check [Scope](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-scopes.html) type of your components. /Maybe it will occur when you use any UI component that annotated [@SessionScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/SessionScope.html)

How you managed routing between these 2 pages.